# Create a mongoose record with a pre-generated id

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying to populate a collection with a manually generated id. I need this to make it easier on testers to provide feedback, as we do search records by ID [among other things].

I defined a `const` array with a few pre-defined keys, and the rest I would like to be generated by mongoose. Below is a fragment filling-up the database with sample data.

```
var col = db.collection('clients')
for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  var client = createClientRecord()
  if (cifs.length > i) {
    client._id = cids[i]
  } else {
    client._id = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId
  }
  console.log('client._id:', client._id)
```

This does not work I like want to. I get as many records as I have in the array. Having a mongoose generated ID does not work. Code just gets stuck there.

Also, I defined my `schema` as:

```
const clientSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  id: {type: String, unique: true, required: true},
  email: { type: String, unique: true, required: true },
  birthName: String,
  ...
})
```

Is this a valid option? Could I manually create unique `id` myself? Should it be `id` or `_id`?

Any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score -3):

You don't need to generate IDs manually as it will be done by Mongoose **automatically**. You just need to define a schema - that's all. And please don't specify 'id' and '_id' fields in a schema. Everything will be handled by Mongoose.

As for the last question ('id' or '_id'), '_id' is a MongoDB id itself (Object ID), but 'id' is a stringified getter for '_id'. 
'id' and '_id' look similar, but the difference in their types. 
'id' is a string, '_id' is an object id, so we have the following condition. They are equal by value, but not by type.

Please note that you may set own ids, but by default it works like explained above.

Please follow this link:
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#id